# Why image url is coming undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to upload the image to firebase and then update that image to db but my code is not working as expected when I am sending an email and pictures from a client to the server my server log logs the email correctly but it logs picture undefined What's wrong with my code and how can I fix it? also my rn cli app image picker is not working as expected when gallery open and when I select an image it quickly starts uploading the image and do not let me edit and crop the image

```
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { firebase } from './config';
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

const PicScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    const SelectImage = async () => {

        const options = {
            mediaType: 'photo',
            quality: 1,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [1, 1],
        };

        ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, async (selectedImage) => {
            if (selectedImage.didCancel) {
                console.log('User cancelled image picker');
            } else if (selectedImage.error) {
                console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', selectedImage.error);
            } else if (selectedImage.customButton) {
                console.log('User tapped custom button: ', selectedImage.customButton);
            } else {
                console.log(selectedImage)
                const source = { uri: selectedImage.assets[0].uri };
                setImage(source.uri);

                const response = await fetch(selectedImage.assets[0].uri);
                const blob = await response.blob();
                const filename = selectedImage.assets[0].uri.substring(selectedImage.assets[0].uri);
                const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(filename);
                const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);
                const url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
                console.log(`hey this is your url `, url)
                return url
            }
        });
    }

    const handleImageUpload = () => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
            .then(data => {
                if (!data) {
                    throw new Error('User data not found')
                }
                setLoading(true)
                SelectImage().then(url => {
                    console.log(url)
                    fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/setpicture', {
                        method: 'post',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            email: JSON.parse(data).user.email,
                            profileimage: url
                        })
                    })
                        .then(res => res.json())
                        .then(data => {
                            if (data.message === 'picture updated successfully') {
                                setLoading(false)
                                alert('picture updated successfully')
                                navigation.navigate('main')
                            } else if (data.error === 'Try Again') {
                                alert('Try Again')
                                setLoading(false)
                                navigation.navigate('login')
                            } else {
                                setLoading(false)
                                alert('Please Try Again')
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.log(err)
                            setLoading(false)
                            alert('Error: ' + err.message)
                        })
                })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                        setLoading(false)
                        alert('Error: ' + err.message)
                    })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                setLoading(false)
                alert('Error: ' + err.message)
            })
    }


    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('main')} style={goback}>
                <AntDesign name="arrowleft" size={24} color="grey" />
                <Text style={{ color: 'grey', fontSize: 16, marginLeft: 5, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Go Back</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>Select Image</Text>
            {
                loading ? <ActivityIndicator size='large' color='white' /> :
                    <Text onPress={() => handleImageUpload()}>Upload</Text>
            }
        </View>
    )
}

export default PicScreen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your function **SelectImage** is not supposed to return image url.
   launchImageLibrary function has callback function parameter in where you return the image url but it's never going to be launchImageLibrary's return value.
   It would be better to place image upload part into the callback function.

   ```
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, async (selectedImage) => {
    if (selectedImage.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
    } else if (selectedImage.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', selectedImage.error);
    } else if (selectedImage.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', selectedImage.customButton);
    } else {
        console.log(selectedImage)
        const source = { uri: selectedImage.assets[0].uri };
        setImage(source.uri);
        const response = await fetch(selectedImage.assets[0].uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const filename = selectedImage.assets[0].uri.substring(selectedImage.assets[0].uri);
        const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(filename);
        const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);
        const url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        console.log(`hey this is your url `, url)
        AsyncStorage.getItem('user').then(data => {
            if (!data) {
                throw new Error('User data not found')
            }
            setLoading(true)
            fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/setpicture', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: JSON.parse(data).user.email,
                    profileimage: url
                })
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data.message === 'picture updated successfully') {
                    setLoading(false)
                    alert('picture updated successfully')
                    navigation.navigate('main')
                } else if (data.error === 'Try Again') {
                    alert('Try Again')
                    setLoading(false)
                    navigation.navigate('login')
                } else {
                    setLoading(false)
                    alert('Please Try Again')
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                setLoading(false)
                alert('Error: ' + err.message)
            })
        });
    }
   ```

   }
2. I think react-native-image-picker has no image crop or edit feature. You can use **react-native-image-crop-picker** instead.